# Oracle Multi Column Subquery with a procedure call

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, subquery, multiple-columns

I have an interesting problem from work. I have an Oracle procedure written by someone else that returns a dataset (multi-column, multi-row) for a single input person ID. I need to use this procedure to get the dataset for all person IDs.

The procedure can be queried by casting the output as a table:

```
"select * from table (package.proc(in_ID))"
```

The only way I know how to query this is to make multiple proc calls like this:

```
select ID,

(select col1 from table(package.proc(persons.ID)) as col1,

(select col2 from table(package.proc(persons.ID)) as col2, --(etc...)

from persons
```

However, for the number of rows and columns I need to get from this thing, this is terribly inefficient and causes server timeouts. Also, the subselects can only get one row from the proc so I also have missing rows (or if it returns more than one row it errors on the subselect).

Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve rewriting the procedure to return the data for all person IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Oracle 12c you could use [`CROSS/OUTER APPLY`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#outer-apply-join):

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons p
OUTER APPLY(TABLE(package.proc(p.ID))) s;
```

Comment: I believe this works. I am getting a lot of blank rows for some reason, but the data I want is there.

Comment: @bobbythefish If function does not return any rows you will get `NULL`. To avoid that you could use `CROSS APPLY`